# Why composer install --no-dev does not work?

Tags: php, composer-php

I am developing a package library which has regular dependencies and one dev dependency. [Composer recommends to not include the `composer.lock` file for libraries](https://getcomposer.org/doc/02-libraries.md#lock-file), so here is the `composer.json`

```json
{
    "name": "myself/mypackage",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.6",
        "nesbot/carbon": "~1.20"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^6.0"
    }
}
```

I want this to be compatible for use with applications running PHP 5.6, and I want to develop it using the latest PHPUnit testing tools which require PHP 7.

On the travis continuous integration testing server, I have a build matrix which runs the PHPUnit tests on PHP > 7 and a linting script:

```
composer install
./lint-php.bash
phpunit
```

and on PHP < 7, simply lint the source code:

```
composer install --no-dev
./lint-php.bash
```

However, it fails because it ignores the `--no-dev` flag and tries to install the dev dependency anyway.

> ```
> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
>
>   Problem 1
>     - phpunit/phpunit 6.0.7 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.5) does not satisfy that requirement.
>     - phpunit/phpunit 6.0.6 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.5) does not satisfy that requirement.
>     - phpunit/phpunit 6.0.5 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.5) does not satisfy that requirement.
>     - phpunit/phpunit 6.0.4 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.5) does not satisfy that requirement.
>     - phpunit/phpunit 6.0.3 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.5) does not satisfy that requirement.
>     - phpunit/phpunit 6.0.2 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.5) does not satisfy that requirement.
>     - phpunit/phpunit 6.0.1 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.5) does not satisfy that requirement.
>     - phpunit/phpunit 6.0.0 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.5) does not satisfy that requirement.
>     - Installation request for phpunit/phpunit ^6.0 -> satisfiable by phpunit/phpunit[6.0.0, 6.0.1, 6.0.2, 6.0.3, 6.0.4, 6.0.5, 6.0.6, 6.0.7].
> ```

Why is it ignoring the `--no-dev` flag? I just want it to install my regular dependencies and to ignore the `require-dev` section.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Despite the [recommendation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/02-libraries.md#lock-file), this is because you don't have a `composer.lock` file, and is actually [a requested feature](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/5016).

First, it tries to resolve *all* dependencies. If this fails, it aborts. Next, it runs the actual install, and at that time ignores the dev dependencies. Your problem is that it couldn't pass the first step for resolution. So it's not that it ignored the `--no-dev` flag, it just never made it that far.

## Option 1

If you include a `composer.lock` file, then it skips the dependency resolution and goes straight to installation at which time it will skip the dev dependencies.

## Option 2

Since you're not including a library, but rather an executable tool, then instead of fighting the potential dependency conflicts between other dev tools you may include later, just pull it out of composer entirely and use [phive (The PHAR Installation and Verification Environment)](https://phar.io/).

Comment: note that since https://github.com/composer/composer/pull/5224 things supposedly have changed a bit.

Comment: @vaxquis haha, yeah in fact I commented on that PR back in 2016 if you read the thread, so my answer still applies in that context :D

Comment: yeah, what I meant was that things were actually *worse* before 5224 ^_~